# How do I apply an indicator to another indicator?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator, recode

I have two indicators with open codes. One of them is an indicator produced by tradingview that counts the classic fixed price-based Renko bricks (or candles) and generates alarms. The other is an indicator that produces percentage-based Renko bricks that are not available in tradingview. How can I apply the Renko bricks counter indicator I have on the indicator that produces percentage-based Renko candles? What code change do I need to make? I think it's simple but I don't know where to start. Please help.

I want to learn how to apply an indicator on another indicator based on its data.

I have added a link for two codes below. Counter Indicator (second one) will run with first indicator's datas.(first one-percent based renko candle generator)

https://uploadnow.io/f/kZgyHbh

Answer (score 0):

First copy the two indicators code in a new indicator windows.
Be careful to only have the 'version' and the indicator declaration line one time only.
Then at the end of the code of the first indicator, you should see the variable which contains the result of this first indicator.
You should use this variable as entry for the second indicator code you paste.

Comment: Thank you so so much but I couldn't do it. Also I couldn't add here two indicator codes. How can I show you that two codes to see?

Comment: @Kosorof2525 you couldn't do what ? You have to be more precise if you want us to be able to help you. It is impossible to solve a problem in the dark. Please update your question with the code.

Comment: I couldnt add here (comments section of the website).Because the codes are long. Ok I am updating my first question.Please look at the codes. Thanks in advance

Comment: I look at your two indicators. You must be more specific about what you try to do, and where you have problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. The second indicator (Counter) counts fixed price-based Renko candles and generates alarms in TV. However, TV doesn’t have an indicator that produces a percent-based Renko candles. I found the first indicator that can produce percent-based Renko candles for price. What I want to do is to count the percentage-based color candles and generate alarms with the Counter indicator. I can't apply these two indicators on TV on each other. So, I want to count the percentage-based color candles and get alarms with a single code. I don't know how to make an input(resource) change.